# I live in New Zealand and have a job offer from an Australian company. It's a remote position. Can I stay in New Zealand and work?

Tags: visa, australia, new-zealand

Irish national living in NZ.

I have a working holiday visa and it runs out in September. Can I apply for a New Zealand Visa with a remote job? Should I get paid in Euro into my European account ? Very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Dara, but I don't think you've got many options to stay permanently if you want to take the Aussie job.

By far the most straightforward options are:

- go and work in Australia and get a working holiday initially, or get sponsored to stay by your new company
- apply for a local job in NZ and get sponsored to stay by a local company.

Alternatively, if you're under 35 and you've been on a standard working holiday visa, you could potentially look at getting an IEP visa to extend your time in NZ by a year? It's not a long term solution though, and there seems to be no definitive answer on whether you should work remotely on that visa.

If you've made your life in NZ or have a partner here and want to stay put, I'd look at local employment.

If you did take the Aussie job, moved over there and eventually qualified for PR, you would be eligible to come back and work in NZ whenever you like :)

Comment: Is it possible to extend my visa by applying for a visitors visa straight after my working holiday visa expires?

Comment: @DaraLynch: Call NZ Immigration. Someone helpful will actually answer the phone (unlike some countries!), and you can discuss your options with them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming NZ visa rules are similar to Australia you need to show you have regular income. However, you need to pay tax. As long as you pay tax their immigration office will make it possible to stay. It is just a matter of whether it is worth to get an income overseas and live n NZ or Australia. Usually it is the other way around as these two countries are quite expensive to live but can male good salaries. Although the tax kills it.
I would suggest write an email or call them. It is unlikely if there is no specific rule (like the ones in the UK which asks you to work so many specific hours to renew your visa) anyone will give you a definitive answer.